# Can't connect to FTPS on port 990

Tags: vsftpd

I am very much new to Linux platform. As I wanted to setup a FTP server using Ubuntu, I installed it and configured the FTP in it. Everything was fine before I enable SSL in vsftpd config file. Apart from default settings, I added the following lines to enable FTP SSL in Ubuntu server.

```
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
# Filezilla uses port 21 if you don't set any port
# in Servertype "FTPES - FTP over explicit TLS/SSL"
# Port 990 is the default used for FTPS protocol.
# Uncomment it if you want/have to use port 990.
listen_port=990
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_max_port=12100
```

Now if I try to access it with ftps (ftps:// I an getting the below error after entering FTP user name.

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection failed.
```

I noticed that it is trying to establish the connection using port 990. I just tried to open port 990 by adding rule in IPtables. The command I used is

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 990 -j ACCEPT
```

But no success.

I request somebody's help to troubleshoot why the connection is not establishing and how I can open necessary ports in Ubuntu.

Comment: The `--sport 990` in your iptables rule is for the source port, but you want to open it as a destination port. Anyway, try to temporarily disable iptables. And are you specifying the destination port in your FTP client? If not, it will default to port 21.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

1. completely disable iptables.
2. tell the service to bind to all the interfaces available, adding this to the config file:

   ```
   listen_address=0.0.0.0
   ```

Once done, try to connect and tell us the results.

Comment: When you write an answer, describe the command to be run, not only describing it. Details how we can *completely disable iptable* (`service iptables stop`, `update-rc.d iptables remove`, ...)

Comment: Ok sorry, I understood it was wide known.

Comment: Yes I tried this. But it didn't work. Still I am unable to login. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if you installed selinux? If so, try "setenforce 0" as root.

Comment: I installed selinux and run setenforce 0 command as root. But no Luck:(

Comment: Hi, I just activated IPtables. Now I am getting connection timeout error after providing the user name for FTPS access.

Comment: I ran " sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 990 -j ACCEPT" to open port 990. After this I am getting same old error message. Any other clues?

Comment: Maybe you forgot "sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT"